# How to open a java application or a jar at startup?

Tags: java, batch-file, startup, executable-jar

I have created a jar. It of coarse work fine. I want that jar to run at start-up automatically. How can I do so??

Comment: Start-up of what? Computer, OS, server, phone...

Comment: In windows computer, place a jar in startup folder

Comment: @TamilSelvan where is that startup folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a .bat file to accomplish this.

`@javaw -jar path/to/jar/your.jar arguments`

(if your jar is an command prompt app, use `@java`)

and then put this .bat file in startup directory.

where is startup directory:

> In windows, you can click the Start button Picture of the Start button , click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open.

Comment: `@javaw -jar path/to/jar/your.jar arguments` what do this mean.. I know nothing about bat file.. I can just create them.... If the address of jar is 'x' then what I have to write

Comment: A cmd window opens and closes instantly at startup but it the jar doesnt get executed...this was what I wrote  ***@javaw -jar C:\Users\Siddharth Yadav\Desktop\Tic-Tac-Toe.jar***

Comment: It has GUI... It works when I execute it manually...

Comment: And the result with that line toooo... Did not work... :(

Comment: There should no blank in the path, so `Siddharth Yadav` is wrong, use a path without blank, and use `@javaw` since your app has GUI

Comment: ***@javaw -jar F:\Tic-Tac-Toe.jar*** This is the line

Comment: What did you get? If you double click the bat, what happens?

Comment: Nothing! the cmd window get opened and closed in a second delay...